# PromQL query to graph the rate of incoming requests

Tags: go, prometheus, promql

I am new to prometheus. I am using a NewCounterVec to log incoming http requests. I used that based on many other people's code that I found on git hub.

Suppose this is how my metric is defined (in go)

```
httpRequests = prometheus.NewCounterVec(
    prometheus.CounterOpts{
        Name: "http_requests_total",
        Help: "Incoming http requests.",
    },
    []string{"path", "status"},
)
```

path the incoming url path and status is the http response status. 
What will be my promQL queries (to draw a graph) for

1. Incoming requests per minute
2. Rate of failure based on http status
   code (status code >=400)

I tried `rate(http_requests_total[5m])[30m:1m]`
based on [this](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/examples/), but that cannot be shown on a graph. It throws an error Error executing query: `invalid expression type "range vector" for range query, must be Scalar or instant Vector`

Answer (score 4):

> Incoming requests per minute

`rate(http_requests_total[5m]) * 60`

> Rate of failure based on http status code (status code >=400)

`rate(http_requests_total{status=~"[45].."}[5m])`

This is however fragile, and will return nothing if there have been no 4xx or 5xx status codes.

Comment: must be like this `rate(http_requests_total{status=~"[45].."}[5m])` with `~`.

Answer (score 1):

The summary requests per minute across all the paths and status codes can be calculated via [increase()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) function:

```
sum(increase(http_requests_total[1m]))
```

The query uses [sum()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum) function for aggregating requests per minute across all the paths and status codes.

The following query returns the number of requests per minute per each `path`:

```
sum(increase(http_requests_total[1m])) by (path)
```

The following query returns summary number of failed http requests per minute across all paths:

```
sum(increase(http_requests_total{status=~"[45].."}[1m]))
```

The following query returns per-`path` number of failed http requests per minute:

```
sum(increase(http_requests_total{status=~"[45].."}[1m])) by (path)
```

Sometimes it may be useful to calculate the percentage of failed requests among all the requests. This can be done with the following query:

```
100 * (
  sum(increase(http_requests_total{status=~"[45].."}[1m]))
    /
  sum(increase(http_requests_total[1m]))
)
```

Per-path percentage of failed requests:

```
100 * (
  sum(increase(http_requests_total{status=~"[45].."}[1m])) by (path)
    /
  sum(increase(http_requests_total[1m])) by (path)
)
```

Note that Prometheus may return fractional results from `increase()` function  even if the `http_requests_total` time series contains only integer values. This is due to the chosen data model - see [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746) and [this comment](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/issues/1215#issuecomment-850305711) for details.